# Detecting scene from viewcontroller

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I am working on a game in Xcode with swift/spritekit.

I want to add the background from the GameViewController but I have different scenes with each different backgrounds: GameScene / MenuScene / MapScene.

Now how do I detect in gameviewcontroller which scene is running so that I can add the right background to it(as UIImage)?

And how do I set Z-position(Z-index) of an UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to track which scene is present yourself. Something like this:

```
class GameViewController {
    var mapScene: SKScene?
    var menuScene: SKScene?
    var gameScene: SKScene?

    var currentScene: SKScene?

    func addBackground() {
        if currentScene === mapScene {
            // ...
        } else if currentScene === menuScene {
            // ...
        } else if currentScene === gameScene {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

If the UIImage is inside an `SKNode`, then you can set its `zPosition` property. If it's just a UIImage in normal UIKit elements, then it's implicit based on when it was added as a subview. If you want it on top, remove it from its parent and re-add it:

```
view.removeFromSuperview()
self.parentView.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: Do I have to change the 4 "SKScene?" in your code? Because like this it doesnt work, when I change the first 3 SKScene? it also doesnt work, what do I have to change the 4th SKScene? in(currentCcene)?

Comment: Sorry, I think in this case you need referential equality (`===`). Answer updated.

Comment: I still can not detect which scene I am in.. the if function is running no matter which scene I am in

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to detect which scene is running if you simply add the appropriate background image in the scene's implementation. Also, I recommend you avoid adding a `UIImage` to your view, since you will need to manually remove it when you transition to a new scene. I suggest you create a sprite node with the background image as its texture and add that to your scene with a negative value for its `zPosition`. Also, you should consider setting the "background" sprite's anchor point and position to `CGPointZero`.

For example, in 'didMoveToView'

```
    let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"MenuSceneBackground")
    backgroundNode.position = CGPointZero
    backgroundNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
    backgroundNode.zPosition = -1000
    addChild(backgroundNode)
```

EDIT: Add the following to remove the gesture recognizers as needed

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
}
```

Comment: But is it true that a spritenode as background will lower the FPS and a UIImage will not?

Comment: Not if you're running on a device. The simulator is not a good indicator of how well/fast a game will run.

Comment: Ok but I also have swipe gestures in my viewcontroller which only work with 1 scene and give error on others. how to fix that if I can't detect scene?

Comment: You should remove all gesture recognizers when you transition to a new scene and add them in the new scene in `didMoveToView`. They are no longer valid once you transition scenes, since they reference the old, released `self` as the target. You can remove the recognizers in `willMoveFromView` in your `SKScene` classes.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to remove a gesture recognizer from the view.

Comment: And how do i add the gesture back when I go to that scene again?

Comment: Move code that adds the gesture recognizer from your view controller to  the scene's `didMoveToView` method.